# Pip install PyInstaller 5.6.2 failed

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

OS: centos 5.8

pip install PyInstaller 5.6.2 failed, due to `pyproject.toml`

```bash
2022-11-22 01:37:27 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting PyInstaller==5.6.2
2022-11-22 01:37:27 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/36/95/32b67f2b6945c34400524284e582025269cf992c6994ff36ed8899e4cf58/pyinstaller-5.6.2.tar.gz (2.4 MB)
2022-11-22 01:37:27 gobuilds.Compile :      â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â” 2.4/2.4 MB 12.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2022-11-22 01:37:28 gobuilds.Compile :   Installing build dependencies: started
2022-11-22 01:37:30 gobuilds.Compile :   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
2022-11-22 01:37:30 gobuilds.Compile :   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile :   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile :   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile :   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting coloredlogs==10.0
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/08/0f/7877fc42fff0b9d70b6442df62d53b3868d3a6ad1b876bdb54335b30ff23/coloredlogs-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile :      â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â” 47.6/47.6 kB 5.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting cvss==2.1
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/97/aa/1aabbb58cd444e9b6e1fa03260bc094aeb149983b2ea717bf4e51b1067c2/cvss-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting retrying==1.3.3
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/44/ef/beae4b4ef80902f22e3af073397f079c96969c69b2c7d52a57ea9ae61c9d/retrying-1.3.3.tar.gz (10 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:31 gobuilds.Compile :   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
2022-11-22 01:37:32 gobuilds.Compile :   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
2022-11-22 01:37:32 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting anchorerunner==0.0.5
2022-11-22 01:37:32 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/api/pypi/rdoss-pypi-local/anchorerunner/0.0.5/anchorerunner-0.0.5.tar.gz (4.8 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:32 gobuilds.Compile :   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
2022-11-22 01:37:32 gobuilds.Compile :   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
2022-11-22 01:37:32 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting vulnerability-parser==0.2.3
2022-11-22 01:37:32 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/api/pypi/rdoss-pypi-local/vulnerability-parser/0.2.3/vulnerability-parser-0.2.3.tar.gz (4.8 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:32 gobuilds.Compile :   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
2022-11-22 01:37:32 gobuilds.Compile :   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting idna<2.8,>=2.5
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/4b/2a/0276479a4b3caeb8a8c1af2f8e4355746a97fab05a372e4a2c6a6b876165/idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile :      â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â” 58.2/58.2 kB 6.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile :      â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â” 133.4/133.4 kB 2.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/01/11/525b02e4acc0c747de8b6ccdab376331597c569c42ea66ab0a1dbd36eca2/urllib3-1.24.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile :      â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â” 118.8/118.8 kB 1.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/1d/38/fa96a426e0c0e68aabc68e896584b83ad1eec779265a028e156ce509630e/certifi-2022.9.24-py3-none-any.whl (161 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile :      â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â” 161.1/161.1 kB 4.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile : Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from PyInstaller==5.6.2->-r requirements.txt (line 10)) (63.2.0)
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2021.4
2022-11-22 01:37:33 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/c2/f1/07071dd00877dd79c68172316d7706e43ee7dcc5b160fb38e65d6466aae9/pyinstaller_hooks_contrib-2022.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (250 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:34 gobuilds.Compile :      â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â” 250.1/250.1 kB 1.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2022-11-22 01:37:34 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting altgraph
2022-11-22 01:37:34 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/cc/ff/88d277ba936d226b0f6dbd6711145f90fcfeed3aa9455c1c2f62c8ffec5b/altgraph-0.17.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:34 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting humanfriendly>=4.7
2022-11-22 01:37:34 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/f0/0f/310fb31e39e2d734ccaa2c0fb981ee41f7bd5056ce9bc29b2248bd569169/humanfriendly-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:34 gobuilds.Compile :      â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â” 86.8/86.8 kB 1.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2022-11-22 01:37:34 gobuilds.Compile : Collecting six>=1.7.0
2022-11-22 01:37:34 gobuilds.Compile :   Downloading https://build-artifactory.eng.vmware.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/packages/packages/d9/5a/e7c31adbe875f2abbb91bd84cf2dc52d792b5a01506781dbcf25c91daf11/six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
2022-11-22 01:37:34 gobuilds.Compile : Building wheels for collected packages: PyInstaller
2022-11-22 01:37:34 gobuilds.Compile :   Building wheel for PyInstaller (pyproject.toml): started
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :   Building wheel for PyInstaller (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :   
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :   Ã— Building wheel for PyInstaller (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :   â”‚ exit code: 1
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :   â•°â”€> [15 lines of output]
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       /build/mts/release/sb-61208562/tmp/pip-build-env-mw4ofo0n/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :         warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       running bdist_wheel
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       running build
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       running build_bootloader
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       No precompiled bootloader found or compile forced. Trying to compile the bootloader for you ...
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       Setting top to                           : /build/mts/release/sb-61208562/tmp/pip-install-zyaakjba/pyinstaller_32ea9bca574042989badd33260a80468/bootloader
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       Setting out to                           : /build/mts/release/sb-61208562/tmp/pip-install-zyaakjba/pyinstaller_32ea9bca574042989badd33260a80468/bootloader/build
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       Python Version                           : 3.10.6 (main, Oct 31 2022, 06:05:46) [GCC 8.2.0]
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : not found
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)        : not found
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       Checking for 'icc' (C compiler)          : not found
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       could not configure a C compiler!
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       (complete log in /build/mts/release/sb-61208562/tmp/pip-install-zyaakjba/pyinstaller_32ea9bca574042989badd33260a80468/bootloader/build/config.log)
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       ERROR: Failed compiling the bootloader. Please compile manually and rerun setup.py
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :       [end of output]
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :   
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile :   ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyInstaller
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile : ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyInstaller, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
2022-11-22 01:37:35 gobuilds.Compile : Failed to build PyInstaller
```

Comment: Have you tried running simply `pip install PyInstaller` ?

Comment: Actually, it executed on a build machine, i'm not able to run `pip install PyInstaller` command on the build machine.
Above error raised when execute `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`， and `requirements.txt` includes PyInstaller 5.6.2